# Ajax: Preflight

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to post a form from `example.com` to `api.example.com` but I'm receiving an error.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hablow.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have already installed the Laravel Cors package from [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

```
<?php
return [
     /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Origin', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

I've tried adding the headers manually in PHP...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

What ever I try seems to fail? Heres my AJAX

```
$("#redeem-key-form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.hablow.net/ajax/account/redeem_key",
        data: $("#redeem-key-form").serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            alert('yay? ' + result);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }       
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You have added the CORS bits to `api.example.com` havn't you, and not `example.com` The receiving site has to set the rules, not the sending site

Comment: both domains run on the same Laravel application.

Comment: the fact that you get a 403 error suggests there is an issue with authentication

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the web server to allow for cors requests. Here is how to do so using ngnix:

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

And for Apache2

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html